# Ubuntu One and Hidden files sync

Tags: ubuntu-one, hidden-files

Libreoffice uses a file to lock documents you are editing that has a .(period) as the first letter of the name.

Ubuntu One does not sync this file so I have no protection from multiple editors of a document at one time.

How do I make Ubuntu One sync every document, including hidden ones?

Thanks.
Mike.

Answer (score 1):

Those files are explicitly excluded because it will sometimes make either the syncdaemon or libreoffice get its knickers in a knot. If you want to test and see if it works for you to have them synced, remove the appropriate line from the "ignore" configuration option in `syncdaemon.conf` (I'm not going to point you at it; if you can't figure it out from here, you won't be able to fix it if it breaks).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to edit the files (actually copy the modified section to the local copy) and the files started syncing.

Mike.